# D3.js - stacked bar with offset for an each category

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new in D3.js. I'm trying to make a stacked bar chart where an each category has a different negative offset. For example I need to move the "Group 1" category on -2 points down and to move the "Group 2" category on -1 point down.

The same behavior has a stacked area chart - negative values in a stack move positive values down. Is it possible with D3.js for a stacked bar? How can I make it?

[Sample in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPdj5.png)

Best regards,
  Sergey

Comment: Please, show us what did you tried.

Comment: I've made the sample with the behavior that I want - [http://jsfiddle.net/19azq4ce/](http://jsfiddle.net/19azq4ce/). The first series is used for making an offset for each category. Generally I need a vertical stacked bar with the similar behavior.